# On text-box length greater then zero clear listbox and disable

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is it possible in java script that when a text box control is populated that it clears my list box and disables it and visa versa.  I'm using ASP.net C# to bind the list box.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="_tx_Zip" On??? runat="server" Width="197px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:ListBox ID="_lb_Zip" runat="server" Height="82px" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="200px">
```

I was messing around with the OnTextChanged event but that's no good. Sorry I'm trying to learn java script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onblur event of javascript and do like...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="_tx_Zip" onblur="update();"

 function update() {
        if (document.getElementById('<%=_tx_Zip.ClientID %>').value != '') {
            document.getElementById('<%=_lb_Zip.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("<%= _lb_Zip.clientID %>").options.length = 0;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%=_lb_Zip.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You ... What event do I use to re-enable it.  This works fin when text is entered however when the text is deleted and I focus back on the listbox it is still disabled ?

Comment: This :document.getElementById("<%= _lb_Zip.clientID %>").options.length = 0; clears the listbox completely how do I just set the selected index to 0 ?

Comment: Use document.getElementById("<%= _lb_Zip.clientID %>").selectedIndex =0